# In-App Purchase Refund

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

I am wondering whether to implement in-app purchase refunds (in case a user refunds). None of the in-app purchase tutorials seem to show how to do it, so I am wondering if that is for a particular reason.

By the way, the in-app purchase is a non-consumable (PRO version).

A big problem I can see with refunds for example, is that you shouldn't remove the PRO features if they don't have connection, but then someone can just use no connection with the app to never get PRO revoke.

My question is: Is there a seamless way to integrate refunds for non-consumables, and do many other apps handle refunds or not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only way for a user to get a refund is to request it from Apple. If granted, the onus is on you to determine this condition. You will have to check receipts actively.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2413/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40016228-CH1-RECEIPT-HOW_DO_I_USE_THE_CANCELLATION_DATE_FIELD_

This states:

> The Cancellation Date (cancellation_date) field is designed for use
>   with auto-renewable subscription, non-consumable and non-renewing
>   subscription products. This field is set when a customer contacts
>   Apple customer support for a refund and the transaction is canceled.

Depending on if your app has a backend or not will dictate a strategy to handle this. If you have a backend, a good method is to periodically check for receipt status (at some time interval of your liking). Note that if you have a large user base, you probably want to divide up the user pool piecewise to do this type of check.

If you don't have this as your option, then you need to make your app make this check.

Or ... you accept that this will happen. I've done work for a company that had a large subscription base and they never ran that check for cancellation/refund (I let them know about that weakness in the system).